# Firefox 57.0.1 renders custom font lower

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, google-fonts

So I'm having trouble with the **Nunito** font from Google Fonts using version 57.0.1 of Firefox. Here is how I'm loading the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v9/6TbRXKWJjpj6V2v_WyRbMevvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

When I apply an underline, the bar appears in the middle of the text and the content is not vertically aligned correctly.

Here is the firefox debugger content when selecting my badly rendered h3 element

```
h3 {
    font-size: 2.92rem;
    margin: 1.46rem 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 110%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Changing the vertical alignment and the line height does not resolve the issue. Once I disable the font family from the debugger, the problem goes away. The font renders perfectly in other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this too. There also appear to be problems with inheritance of vertical alignment for inline span elements.

I solved the issue by switching to "Nunito Sans"